# Windows store apps Hub Control Horizontal Offset

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How is it possible to determine the horizontal offset of the Windows 8.1 HubControl?

I would like to adjust the margin of my title by the amount of horizontal offset.

Interestingly I notice in the Bing News app that the title 'Bing News' starts off white when it is over the lead image. However, when you scroll right, and the title is now over the application's (light) background (having scrolled past the image), the title background colour now changes to black.

See image below. Shows the top most part of the screen. Images 1-3 show when the page has scrolled right and the BING NEWS title has changed colour once it is no longer over the image.

[image]

I assume this is done via the offset again so I hope that my idea is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Hub` control has a child element which is a `ScrollViewer`. You can parse the visual tree to retrieve the `ScrollViewer`, or you can use some neat extensions such as the ones in [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com) which allow you to do a call such as `myHubControl.GetFirstDescendentOfType<ScrollViewer>()`. Then, you can retrieve the `HorizontalOffset` from this object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That sounds like what I'm after. I've just added the nuget package to my project. I can't seem to find the method you mention. Do you know what namespace that is under in the toolkit?

Comment: I ended up creating my own extension method which achieves the same thing as using the toolkit.